# Limit pull request from a specific branch to target branch - BitBucket

Tags: bitbucket

My team is using BitBucket for Git repositories. We plan to go live in next two months and what I want to do is to limit so that the pull requests can be only made from a specific branch to the 'production' branch.

I am aware of the Branch Permission sections of the BitBucket but that solves by limiting the 'Changes without a pull request' only half the issue.

What I want to achieve is that there should be no changes allowed without approved pull request **and** this pull request can only be made from a specific branch.
If the pull request is made from any other 'random' branch to the 'production' branch the pull request could get automatically denied.

Is such a thing possible? Thanks.

Comment: Bitbucket PRs are a Bitbucket feature (Git does not have pull requests, which is why GitLab calls theirs "merge requests" for instance) so this is entirely up to Bitbucket. I don't know of any such feature but I don't actually *use* Bitbucket myself.

Comment: Great feature request! Is this for bitbucket cloud (as in bitbucket.org) or Bitbucket server/data center (you install/host)

Comment: @dev_doctor in my case it's for BitBucket server/data center. But I think it would make sense to have such feature available in general. I think it would be a valuable addition.